# Reshape data frame for consecutive years

Tags: r, reshape, riverplot

I have data about thousands of customers who visited stores in the 3 past years.
For each customer, I have :

- ID
- Combination of a year and the first store visited in this year.

> ```
> Customer_Id | Year_*_Store 
> 1            2010_A
> 1            2011_B
> 1            2012_C
> 2            2010_A
> 2            2011_B
> 2            2012_D
> ```

What I’d like to have is the following structure of data in order to visualize the evolution of the customers’behaviour with a riverplot( aka Sankey plot)

For instance the 2 customers, who firstly visited the store A in 2010, firstly visited the store B in 2011:

```
SOURCE |     TARGET |   NB_CUSTOMERS
2010_A      2011_B      2
2011_B      2012_C      1
2011_B      2012_D      1
```

I don't want links between two years which are not consecutive like 2010_A and 2012_D

### **How can I do that in R ?**

Comment: Are the shop visits in increasing chronological order for each customer?

Comment: What have you tried so far (i.e. is there an existing 'inelegant" solution that you're looking to optimize)?

Comment: Highly relevant to oh so many posts on SO: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Despite the sarcastic sound of it, he has put in a lot of thought in the post and has some points a good programmer must understand.

Comment: @alexis_laz : Yes I ordered them chronologically.

For now I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can't have a `*` in column names (see `?make.names`). Here is a basic approach:

1. Split `Year_store` into two separate columns `Year` and `Store` in your data frame; at the moment it contains two completely different kinds of data and you actually need to process them separately.
2. Make a `NextYear` column, defined as `Year + 1`
3. Make a `NextStore` column, in which you assign the store code matching `Customer_Id` and for which `Year` is the same as this row's `NextYear`, assigning `NA` if there is no record of the customer visiting a store the next year, and throwing an error if the data do not meet the required specification (are ambiguous about which store was visited first the next year).
4. Strip out any of the rows in which `NextStore` is `NA`, and combine the `NextYear` and `NextStore` columns into a `NextYear_NextStore` column.
5. Summarize your data frame by the `Year_store` and `NextYear_NextStore` columns e.g. using `ddply` in the `plyr` package.

Some sample data:

```
# same example data as question
customer.df <- data.frame(Customer_Id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    Year_Store = c("2010_A", "2011_B", "2012_C", "2010_A", "2011_B", "2012_D"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# alternative data should throw error, customer 2 is inconsistent in 2011
badCustomer.df <- data.frame(Customer_Id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
    Year_Store = c("2010_A", "2011_B", "2012_C", "2010_A", "2011_B", "2011_D"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And an implementation:

```
require(plyr)

splitYearStore <-  function(df) {
    df$Year <- as.numeric(substring(df$Year_Store, 1, 4))
    df$Store <- as.character(substring(df$Year_Store, 6))
    return(df) 
}

findNextStore <- function(df, matchCust, matchYear) {
    matchingStore <- with(df,
        df[Customer_Id == matchCust & Year == matchYear, "Store"])
    if (length(matchingStore) == 0) {
        return(NA)
    } else if (length(matchingStore) > 1) {
        errorString <- paste("Inconsistent store results for customer",
            matchCust, "in year", matchYear)
        stop(errorString)
    } else {
        return(matchingStore)
    }
}

tabulateTransitions <-  function(df) {
    df <- splitYearStore(df)
    df$NextYear <- df$Year + 1
    df$NextStore <- mapply(findNextStore, matchCust = df$Customer_Id,
        matchYear = df$NextYear, MoreArgs = list(df = df)) 
    df$NextYear_NextStore <- with(df, paste(NextYear, NextStore, sep = "_"))
    df <- df[!is.na(df$NextStore),]
    df <- ddply(df, .(Source = Year_Store, Target = NextYear_NextStore),
        summarise, No_Customers = length(Customer_Id))
    return(df) 
}
```

Results:

```
> tabulateTransitions(customer.df)
  Source Target No_Customers
1 2010_A 2011_B            2
2 2011_B 2012_C            1
3 2011_B 2012_D            1
> tabulateTransitions(badCustomer.df)
Error in function (df, matchCust, matchYear)  : 
  Inconsistent store results for customer 2 in year 2011
```

No attempt has been made to optimise; if your data set is massive then perhaps you should investigate a `data.table` solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't expected a such complete answer !

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with dplyr (faster)

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="Customer_Id  Year_Store 
1            2010_A
1            2011_B
1            2012_C
2            2010_A
2            2011_B
2            2012_D")

require(dplyr)             # for aggregation
require(riverplot)         # for Sankey

targets<-
group_by(df,Customer_Id) %.%           # group by Customer
mutate(source=Year_Store,target=c(as.character(Year_Store)[-1],NA)) %.%   # add a lag to show the shift
filter(!is.na(target)) %.%                                                # filter out empty edges
regroup(list("source","target")) %.%                                      # regroup by source & target
summarise(len=length(Customer_Id)) %.%                                    # count customers for relationship
mutate(step=as.integer(substr(target,1,4))-as.integer(substr(source,1,4))) %.%   # add a step to show how many years
filter(step==1)                                                            # filter out relationships for non consec years

topnodes <- c(as.character(unique(df$Year_Store)))                         # unique nodes

nodes <- data.frame( ID=topnodes,                                          # IDs
                   x=as.numeric(substr(topnodes,1,4)),                     # x value for plot
                   col= rainbow(length(topnodes)),                         # color each different
                   labels= topnodes,                                       # labels
                   stringsAsFactors= FALSE )

edges<-                                                                    # create list of list 
  lapply(unique(targets$source),function(x){
      l<-as.list(filter(targets,source==x)$len)                            # targets per source
      names(l)<-filter(targets,source==x)$target                           # name of target
      l
  })

names(edges)<-unique(targets$source)                                       # name top level nodes

r <- makeRiver( nodes, edges)                                              # make the River 
plot( r )                                                                  # plot it!
```

[image]

Comment: I was about to add "or dplyr" as an alternative to exploring data.table, do you have any idea how the two would compare on speed for this kind of task?

Comment: @Silverfish my gut feel it that `dplyr` would be slightly faster because of all the manipulation, but it probably depends on the size of the aggregation groups compared to the overall table. Both quick, though - I like this because you can see the logical iterations. The real bottleneck here will probably be creating the `edges` list for the `makeRiver()` function - I guess it would be quicker to create the underlying river list directly.